# Concatenating elements and Collections into a new Collection

Tags: java, collections

I have a `Collection` of elements and a single element. I want my getter function looks a little like this

```
public List<Element> getElements(boolean includeOtherElement){

    if (includeOtherElement){
        return elements + otherElement; //Obviously this doesn't work, but I'm looking for something that would work like this
    }

    return elements;

}
```

Is there a way I could acheive this behavior in a single line, such as with the Stream API or something similar?

EDIT:

I have since realized that I should not be modifying state in a getter method.

Comment: `elements.add( otherElement )` and don't return

Comment: @svasa would it be preferable to make a copy of the List, then add the element and return it?

Comment: I would prefer not to have to make a copy of the Collection. The purpose of this question was whether there was a solution that did not require introducing a local variable

Comment: Why don't you want to use a local variable?

Comment: I find that the code is cleaner and easier to follow (for me at least) if I don't. It's more of just a personal preference, and I was curious to see if anyone had a solution that worked.

Comment: Is there any access from this method to original list?

Comment: @patrick-hainge Why a copy ? Unnecessary memory usage. Just add it to your existing list.

Comment: @svasa A getter method shouldn't modify state, and OP has specifically said that list shouldn't be modified. *(answer with that comment has been deleted)*

Comment: @Andreas I didn't realize OP wanted a new list. As per getter yes I understand it shouldn't modify state of the object, but I have seen methods that are inadvertently named getXXX even though they modify the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to add otherElement to the elements list but still want to return a list, you will have to provide a new list.

Simple way:

```
public List<Element> getElements(boolean includeOtherElement){

    if (includeOtherElement){
        List<Element> extendedList = new ArrayList<>(elements);
        extendedList.add(otherElement);
        return extendedList;
    }

    return elements;
}
```

This would create a shallow copy of your list.

If you really want to, you could provide your own list implementation, which delegates the first indices to the elements list and the last index to the otherElement;

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do not want your getter function to be changing variables. I would recommend doing something like `temp = elements` to return a temp variable, with the extra element added via `temp.add(otherElement)`. This way you will not change your current variable while still eliciting the same behavior.

Comment: @AndreKulpa Thank you for pointing out that I was improperly using a getter method. I will just change how the state is modified, as the way I was doing it previous was improper for OOP

Comment: `temp = elements` does *not* copy the list, so what's the point of the `temp` variable? The `elements` list is still being updated.

Comment: Yes, I should have been a bit more specific with my `temp = elements` statement. He would want to make a shallow copy and simply append that new element. I was simply stating you would want a temp variable holding that shallow copy to keep with the proper OOP conventions.

Comment: @AndrewKulpa But don't you think the difference between `a = b` and `a = copy(b)` is extremely relevant here? To the point of making this answer a very bad answer, since it leads to logic errors if followed as written?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answer will work exactly for you but I think it is a good example of something that is possible with the API. The reason that it may or may not be usable in a particular case is that it depends on the location of the extra element(s) being constant in the list.

Suppose it was the case that you didn't want to create a copy of the list, because you actually *wanted* whoever calls the getter to be able to modify the list. Or, suppose that you just didn't want to make a defensive copy of the list, perhaps because the list is very, very large. In these cases you don't want to add or remove the extra element from the list, you want to return a *view* of the list which either includes or excludes the extra element.

This is actually possible with existing API, using the [`List.subList(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) method. `subList` doesn't create a copy, like e.g. `String.substring(...)` does. Rather, the returned sublist is mutable (if the original list was), and changes to the sublist show through to the original list.

(Though I should note that the semantics of the sublist become undefined if the backing list is structurally modified, i.e. you shouldn't add/remove to and from the original list while keeping a reference to the sublist. If you change the original list through a reference other than the sublist, you have to create a new sublist.)

So what you could do is keep a complete list with all of the elements, then return a sublist of the range which excludes the element(s) you don't want to return.

This could also be used in conjunction with [`Collections.unmodifiableList(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-) if the code which calls the getter is not supposed to be able to mutate the list.

Here's an example which shows this in action:

```
import java.util.*;

class Example {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Example e = new Example();
        List<Object> sub = e.getList(false);
        // sublist is [1, 2, 3]
        System.out.printf("sublist is %s%n", sub);
        sub.add(0, -1);
        sub.add(1,  0);
        sub.add(5);
        // sublist is [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5]
        System.out.printf("sublist is %s%n", sub);
        List<Object> all = e.getList(true);
        // full list is [element0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5]
        System.out.printf("full list is %s%n", all);
        // As a side-note, this sequence of calls is
        // e.g. what you aren't supposed to do:
        // all.add(something); // <- structural modification
        // sub.add(another);   // <- this is undefined
        // You have to make a new sublist first:
        // sub = e.getList(false);
        // sub.add(another);   // <- this is fine now
    }

    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Example() {
        objects.add("element0");
        objects.add(1);
        objects.add(2);
        objects.add(3);
    }

    List<Object> getList(boolean includeElement0) {
        if (includeElement0) {
            return objects;
        } else {
            return objects.subList(1, objects.size());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the example on Ideone: http://ideone.com/PloZCh.

---

Also, while not returning a `List`, this can be done by returning a `Stream`:

```
Stream<E> stream = list.stream();
if (includeOtherElement) {
    return Stream.concat(stream, Stream.of(otherElement));
} else {
    return stream;
}
```

I suppose this may be the canonical way to do such a thing in Java 8.